# Why I don't lose postgresql data when rebuild docker image?

Tags: postgresql, docker

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Why I don't lose data when running `docker-compose build --force-em --no-cache`. If this is normal, why do we need to create volume for data folder ?

Comment: It's not normal if data is not in a volume, try trop stop, rm and rebuild properly.
docker-compose stop, docker-compose rm, docker-compose up

Comment: So, we don't need to create a volume to preserve data ?

Comment: no, you need to create volume to preserve data. Keep data without volume is not normal. (Sry for my english)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When running the command `docker-compose build --force-em --no-cache`, this will only build the web Docker image from the `Dockerfile` which in your case is in the same directory.

This command will not stop the containers that you have previously started using this compose file, thus you want lose any data when running this command.

However, as soon as you remove the containers  using `docker-compose down` or when containers are stopped `docker-compose rm`, you won't find the postgres data when you restart the container.

If you want to persist the data, and make the container pick it up when it is recreated, you need to give the postgres data volume a name as such.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Now the postgres data won't be lost when the containers are recreated.

Comment: TY. I didn't know that container is able to store persistent data, I thought it is just a running process of an image